# How to create 1 million processes

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, process, fork

My goal here is to simply compare performance of creating 1 million processes vs threads (sequentially). Each process/thread does nothing, and they should only run after the current one has finished.

Below is my code. When I compile it, I get several instances of the error:

```
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

What is going on?

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

int numberOfActions = 0;
int i;

if(argc != 3){
    printf("usage: <thread/process> <number_of_threads/processes>\n");
    exit(1);
}

numberOfActions = atoi(argv[2]); //number of threads/processes
if(strcmp(argv[1], "p") == 0){
    printf("process\n");
    int pid;
    int status;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfActions; i++){
        pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0){//fork failed
            printf("fork failed\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else{//fork succeeded
            if(pid == 0){//child
                continue;
            }
            else{//parent
                waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
                exit(0);
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
else{
    printf("thread\n");
    pthread_t tidp;
    int thread0;
    int parameter = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfActions; i++){
        thread0 = pthread_create(&tidp, NULL, &continueThread, (void*) &parameter);
        if(thread0 != 0) printf("\ncan't create thread\n");
        pthread_join(tidp, NULL);
    }
}

return 1;

}
```

Comment: What does `ulimit -u` say? That's your per-user process limit.

Comment: I'm not aware of any OS that will allow a million processes.

Comment: I mean to run them subsequently, apologies for the confusion. -Each thread and process should run after the other ends. Each process and thread does absolutely NOTHING

Comment: Why are you constructing a fan heater?  Can you not just buy one from your local electrical store?

Comment: @MartinJames: it says in the question, "to simply compare performance of creating 1 million processes vs threads". All performance measurements are room heaters.

Comment: I don't think subsequently was the adjective you were looking for. perhaps *sequentially*, or *in series*.

Comment: @WhozCraig: that's because it's an adverb ;-p

Comment: @SteveJessop thus why I only pulled 780 instead of 800 on my verbal-sats. Thank God my math carried my water. I really need to *start* drinking in the afternoon.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I English correctly sometimes :p

Comment: Me fail English? That's unpossible!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, each child immediately creates another child. So you aren't running the processes consecutively. Each parent will not exit until after its child exits, so in fact you're trying to create 1 million processes all at the same time.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < numberOfActions; i++){
    pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0){//fork failed
        printf("fork failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{//fork succeeded
        if(pid == 0){//child
            exit(0);
        }
        else{//parent
            waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! here are my results: 

1 million processes 
real  2m59.607s

;1 million threads
real  0m43.103s